# Exclude pfx file from packaging apk

Tags: android, gradle

I want to exclude this file from apk --> /src/main/res/raw/file.pfx
I tried the below options, but nothing has worked. please guide me on this.Thanks!

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            resources {
                exclude '**/file.pfx'
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude '**/file.pfx'
}
```

Comment: Delete the file from the project, or at least move it out of `res/raw/`. Why is it there?

Comment: Which is in a third party library, I was just trying to remove it automatically instead of removing it every time when updating the library.